# Who are the members of the International Theological Commission for the 10th Quinquennium?

Tags: catholicism, papal-magisterium

About the [International Theological Commission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Theological_Commission):

> The International Theological Commission (ITC) of the Catholic Church advises the Magisterium of the Church, particularly the Congregation for the Doctrine of the Faith (CDF), a dicastery of the Roman Curia.[1][2] Its memberships consists of no more than 30 Catholic theologians[1] appointed by the pope at the suggestion of the Prefect of the CDF[3] for renewable five year terms. They tend to meet annually for a week in Rome, where the Commission is based.[4]
>
> The Prefect of the CDF is *ex officio* the president of the ITC.

[This Vatican.va page](https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cfaith/cti_documents/rc_cti_index-members_en.html) lists the last members of the 2014-2019 (9th) Quinquennium (appointed July 2014) as well as the past members of the 8th to 1st Quinquennium (appointed May 1969).

The last appointment (July 2014) was [reported by the Catholic News Agency](https://www.catholicnewsagency.com/news/30565/roster-of-women-increases-on-vatican-theological-board) on Sep 24, 2014.

On 29 November 2019, Pope Francis had an [audience with the members of the 9th Quinquennium ITC](http://www.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/speeches/2019/november/documents/papa-francesco_20191129_commissione-teologica.html) celebrating 50 years of ITC work with the following quote, indicating that a new Quinquennium would be appointed soon:

> I am pleased to meet you and I thank your president, Cardinal Ladaria, for the words he addressed to me on your behalf. **You have reached the end of your ninth five-year period of work**, but above all to an important anniversary, the fiftieth anniversary of the Commission: fifty years of service to the Church. I congratulate you on this Jubilee, which allows you to make grateful memory of your history.

In the preliminary note of the ITC document [The Reciprocity between Faith and Sacraments in the Sacramental Economy](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cfaith/cti_documents/rc_cti_20200303_reciprocita-fede-sacramenti_en.html) produced by the 9th Quinquennium and released in December 2019, there was an indication that the term has been extended by 1 year.

**My Question**: Who are the current members of the International Theological Commission for the 10th Quinquennium that Pope Francis should have appointed in 2019 / 2020?

Comment: +1 Not so easy to find a source!

Comment: @KenGraham Yes, I tried but couldn't find it.

Comment: nine quinquenniums comes to 45 years, yet the fiftieth anniversary has been celebrated. This may suggest that a gap between quinquenniums may happen, and it is therefore possible a new one has not yet been appointed.

Comment: @davidlol What seemed to happen was probably frequent extensions rather than gap (commission is dissolved with new one not yet appointed).  If the 9th is still now operating this would make the 9th the longest. The last longest was the 6th: 6 yr 4 mo. Complete history of appointment dates: 1st May 1969 ; 2nd Aug 1974 ; 3rd Aug 1980 ; 4th May 1986 ; 5th Jul 1992 ; 6th Oct 1997 ; 7th Feb 2004 ; 8th Jun 2009 ; 9th Jul 2014

Comment: @GratefulDisciple  Your extract mentions they tend to meet annually for a week in Rome. With the current world situation this is not possible so maybe that is  delaying announcing a new commission.

Comment: @davidlol Yes, that must be a contributing factor.  At any rate, I'm looking forward to finding out who the new members are, to see the theological direction that the church is going.

Comment: @davidlol  It's finally announced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On July 27, 2021, Pope Francis appointed 12 new theologians and renewed 16 members of the International Theological Commission to serve as the [10th Quinquennium (2021-2026)](https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cfaith/cti_documents/rc_cti_index-members_en.html#List_of_the_Members_for_the_2021-2026_Quinquennium) with its first plenary session to take place in 2022. The appointments were announced in a [Sep 29, 2021 Press release](https://press.vatican.va/content/salastampa/en/bollettino/pubblico/2021/09/29/210929c.html) by the Vatican.

[*Catholic News Agency*](https://www.catholicnewsagency.com/news/249131/us-theologians-appointed-to-vatican-s-international-theological-commission) article and [*National Catholic Register*](https://www.ncregister.com/cna/u-s-theologians-appointed-to-vatican-s-international-theological-commission) article have brief profiles of the new members.  According to both articles, the 1 year delay was due to coronavirus pandemic.

**List of 2021-2026 ITC members**:

| Name | Country |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Edouard Adé | Benin | New |
| Sr. Alenka Arko, comloy | Slovenia - Russian Fed |  |
| Yury Avvakumov | Germany – Ukraine | New |
| Msgr. Antonio Luiz Catelan Ferreira | Brazil |  |
| Msgr. Piero Coda | Italy | Secretary General |
| Alberto Cozzi | Italy | New |
| Fr. Peter Dubovský, S.I. | Slovakia |  |
| Fr. Jorge J. Ferrer, S.I. | Puerto Rico | New |
| Mario Ángel Flores Ramos | Mexico |  |
| Fr. Simon Francis Gaine, O.P. | Great Britain | New, [OP PR](https://www.op.org/brother-simon-francis-gaine-op/) |
| Carlos María Galli | Argentina |  |
| Gaby Alfred Hachem | Lebanon |  |
| Reinhard Huetter | USA | New, [CUA PR](https://communications.catholic.edu/news/2021/09/pope-francis-appoints-catholic-university-professors-to-international-theological-commission.html) |
| Marek Jagodzinski | Poland | New |
| Fr. Thomas Kollamparampil, C.M.I. | India |  |
| Victor Ronald La Barrera Villarreal | Perù | New |
| Karl-Heinz Menke | Germany |  |
| Sr. Isabell Naumann, I.S.S.M. | Australia | New, [news](https://www.catholicweekly.com.au/pope-appoints-sydney-schoenstatt-sister-isabell-naumann-issm-to-top-body/) |
| Sr. Josee Ngalula, R.S.A. | Congo | New |
| John Junyang Park | Korea |  |
| Fr. Bernard Pottier, S.I. | Belgium |  |
| Javier Prades López | Spain |  |
| Marianne Schlosser | Germany - Austria |  |
| Nicholaus Segeja M’hela | Tanzania |  |
| Fr. Gabino Uríbarri Bilbao, S.I. | Spain |  |
| Philippe Vallin | France |  |
| Fr. Etienne Vetö, I.C.N. | France - USA | New |
| Robin Darling Young | USA | New, [CUA PR](https://communications.catholic.edu/news/2021/09/pope-francis-appoints-catholic-university-professors-to-international-theological-commission.html) |

**List of 2014-2019 ITC members no longer serving**:

| Name | Country |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Terwase Henry Akaabiam | Nigeria |  |
| Sr Prudence Allen, R.S.M. | USA |  |
| Fr. Serge-Thomas Bonino, O.P. | France |  |
| Msgr. Lajos Dolhai | Hungary |  |
| Msgr. Krzysztof Gózdz | Poland |  |
| Koffi Messan Laurent Kpogo | Togo |  |
| Oswaldo Martínez Mendoza | Colombia |  |
| Prof. Moira Mary McQueen | Canada – Great Britain |  |
| Prof. Tracey Rowland | Australia | [news](https://www.catholicweekly.com.au/pope-appoints-sydney-schoenstatt-sister-isabell-naumann-issm-to-top-body/) |
| Prof. Héctor Gustavo Sánchez Rojas, S.C.V. | Peru |  |
| Pierangelo Sequeri | Italy |  |
| Željko Tanjic | Croatia |  |
| Fr. Gerard Francisco P. Timoner III, O.P. | Philippines |  |
| Fr. Thomas G. Weinandy, O.F.M.Cap. | USA |  |